# WebView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

I set following properties to show my Website on WebView in info.plist of iOS project. Now my website is opening on iOS project properly. Now I want to set same properties on Android projects to but I don't know similar solution in Android.manifest of android project.

[image]

My code for WebView is-

```
public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var browser = new WebView();

            browser.Source = "http://m.ugoparty.com/";

            Content = browser;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are having on Android with the WebView?

Comment: The page is taking time to load and after few second, it shows web page is not available.

Comment: I allows Internet from manifest file too.

Comment: There should not really be anything preventing you from visiting the site. Do you see any errors or more info in the Output Window/Android Log?

Answer (score 0):

Am Im missing something here you don't need to change any properties in your android project the webview should load your site just fine in your android project those settings are only needed for your iOS project because ios 9.x prevent you from accessing non **https** urls

Comment: It shows Webpage not found on android but same page showing on iOS.